# How would you efficiently calculate an adjacency matrix of an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix

I am attempting to convert an image to a graph by obtaining an adjacency matrix in matlab using the following example code:

```
im = im2single(imread('cameraman.tif')); 
% It is safe to assume that I need such a small adjacency matrix.
% therefore I resize the image below. 
im = imresize(im,[16 16]);

[rows, cols, bands] = size(im);
imr = reshape(im, rows*cols, bands);
adj_matrix = zeros(rows*cols, rows*cols);
for ind = 1:rows*cols
    dist = sum((imr - imr(ind,:)).^2,2);
    adj_matrix(ind,:) = dist;
end
```

Though the code is fast for a single image, I wish to scale it to large batches and run it on a gpu. So my aim is two fold:

1. Is there a way to run this without the for loop?
2. Is there a way to run this on a batch, ergo a tensor [W x H x Num_of_Images]

Many thanks!

Comment: Check out [`pdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html).

Comment: pdist is very good. However it has one problem, i don't understand how you can use if effectively for batches without a for loop.